# Modifying callout marker

Tags: plotting, labeling

I want to remove the blue circles that appear as callout markers. How can I do that?

```
A = LogLogPlot[(x^5 - x^4 + x), {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[A, ListLogLogPlot[{{Callout[{2.5, 100}, Style["Test"], Above,LabelStyle -> {10, Bold, Blue}]}}]]
```

Is it also possible to change the color of blue circle, for example, one to red and the other to green?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] = x^5 - x^4 + x;

A = LogLogPlot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red];
```

To color each dot separately, make each `Callout` a separate list and use `PlotStyle` to specify their color. Likewise, using `PlotStyle -> Opacity[0]` will eliminate the dots (make them fully transparent).

```
Show[A,
 ListLogLogPlot[{
   {Callout[{2.5, f[2.5]}, Style["Test-1"], Above, 
     LabelStyle -> {10, Bold, Blue},
     Background -> Opacity[0]]},
   {Callout[{0.5, f[0.5]}, Style["Test-2"], Above, 
     LabelStyle -> {10, Bold, Blue}]}},
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The code you have doesn't generate that image, but I can hazard a guess. The blue circles are the output of the `ListLogLogPlot` command, not the `Callout` which consists of the line and the label. You can use `CalloutStyle` as an option to `Callout` to change the color of the line but it would not change the color of the blue circle in your case.

You could use the `PlotStyle` argument of `ListLogLogPlot` or modify your `Callout` like

```
ListPlot @ {Callout[
  Style[{2.5, 100}, Green], 
  Style["Test", FontSize -> 14, Bold, Blue], 
  Above, 
  CalloutStyle -> Orange
]}
```

to style each element individually.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need a separate plot only for the callout. You can do this with a single plot:

```
LogLogPlot[Callout[(x^5 - x^4 + x), "Test", {2.5, 100}], {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]